# Is the asymptotic behavior invariant under algebraic manipulations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics

I was just dealing with a problem - actually it was a question on [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245527/standard-normal-quantile-approximation) - of some asymptotic results and while doing so I asked myself whether we are free of doing some algebraic manipulations under which the equivalence relation is invariant:

> Let's science up: say we have two functions $f$ and $g$ and we define
>    an equivalence relation  $$ f\sim g \iff \lim_{n\to
>  \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1 $$

could we now also say for example
$$
f+1\sim g+1 \text{ or } \log f\sim \log g \tag1
$$
the specific question I had in mind was whether 
$$
1-f\sim g \iff f\sim 1-g \tag{2a}
$$
holds or not. Which means in the actual problem setting of the above [linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245527/standard-normal-quantile-approximation), if we can deduce any information from 
$$
1 - \Phi(x) \sim\frac{\phi(x)}{x}  \tag{2b}
$$
with $\Phi(x)$ CDF of the standard normal and $\phi(x)$ corresponding density, to
$$
\Phi(x)\sim \;? \tag3
$$Sure there are a lot of examples where $(1)$ holds, but I am not sure if this is generally true. Also $(2)$ is definitely not true in general (take $x-1$ and $x$) - is it maybe true in this special case? Can we maybe slightly modify the above relation to make it being invariant under such operations?

Comment: Considering the definition of $\sim$ it works nicely with multiplication and division but that's pretty much it. You're better off just handling everything else on a case-by-case basis than searching for a general rule of this form.

Comment: @AntonioVargas yeah, you're probably right, thanks. I actually was just wondering if there is a relation between $(2b)$ and $(3)$. Actually one could try an asymptotic series expansion - my feeling says that a constant shouldn't matter, and a sign also not if one is interested only in the *growth class*. Do you know whether there is a canonical definition of $\sim$ which an author could mean if there is no explanation whatsoever mentioned?

Comment: I've only ever seen one rigorous definition of $\sim$, which is the one at the top of your post. (It also has meaning when considering complete asymptotic expansions but unless you see a $\Sigma$ it's irrelevant.) Note that many fields use $\sim$ without defining it and especially use it in ways which either conflict with the rigorous definition or which yield trivial statements when interpreted precisely using the rigorous definition. If it is not clear what someone means when they use $\sim$ then it should be clarified or the offender should be put to death.